# Error in publishing the project in the Play Market

Tags: java, android, firebase

I wrote a project in Android Studio and wanted to put it now in the Play Market, but I have an error that the package contains the name exampe, looked at other answers and say that you need to create a new project with a different name. Is it really necessary to create a new project and rewrite all the code? I have a second application in development that I have been writing for three months now, do I need to create everything all over again? Or is there any way to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for creating a new project again just change the `applicationId` to whatever you want (for example `com.korsun.pavel.myapp`) this is the one that should be unique in google play.
And don't worry about the package name in AndroidManifest.xml, just make sure the package name in the manifest file is the same as the package you created for your source code.

`applicationId` Can be different from them, and `applicationId` is the one checked by google play.
I myself have a few apps on the store with `applicationId` different then package name in the manifest file.

Note: All the google services like firebase the package name there should be equal to `applicationId`. Ideally, your `applicationId` should be equal to your manifest package name but you can have different.